# how does pip find dependencies?

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm trying to install some packages with pip on a computer where I do not have root access.  I'm running into some problems with the dependencies.  Basically, I install a package 1:

```
cd path/to/package1
pip install . --install-option="--prefix=path/to/my/install/dir"
```

but when I try to install package 2:

```
cd path/to/package2
pip install . --install-option="--prefix=path/to/my/install/dir"
```

It cannot find package 1.  How do I set the directory where it looks for dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) - it makes package management right.

This way, you first create virtualenv:

```
 $ virtualenv aaa
 Using base prefix '/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1'
 New python executable in /Users/el/tmp/aaa/bin/python3.5
 Also creating executable in /Users/el/tmp/aaa/bin/python
 Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

then

```
$ source aaa/bin/activate
```

This sets environment variables and all new installations `pip` will do in this folder.

When you finish work with it, just do:

```
$ deactivate
```

Now you exited from virtualenv to usual "system" one.

As a result:

- Your environment is isolated from operation system's one
- You cannot break system libraries
- You may have have different virtualenvs for different programs. And they may have incompatible together modules
- You may easily fix modules versions with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Now this file contains all modules with pinned versions in easy format:

  ```
  appdirs==1.4.0
  packaging==16.8
  pyparsing==2.1.10
  six==1.10.0
  ```
- You may recreate this environment from scratch, just using:

  ```
  $ virtualenv folder 
  $ source ./folder/bin/activate
  $ pip install -r requirements.txt
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question but does fix the underlying problem --- installing using

```
pip install . --user
```

installs everything in a local directory that pip knows to look in.